# Angular pagination using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, pagination, numbers, primeng

I'm trying to paginate a table in my Angular project. 
Doing the following:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { PaginatorModule } from 'primeng/paginator';
```

**component.html**

```
<p-table [columns]="bookCols" [value]="bookList" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" >

<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let bookCol of bookCols">
            {{bookCol.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-book let-columns="bookCols">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let bookCol of bookCols">
                {{book[bookCol.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Pagination is working fine, but the entire experience is reduced on simple blue numbers [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY3mf.png), not at all something that the official page is providing [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/page)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular.json file should be like that

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",

],
```

Answer (score 1):

include in **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",

],
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in **.angular-cli.json file**. Best practise is to add the style details

```
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
        "styles.scss"  //external style sheet 
      ],
```